# regex search for two characters including one symbol

Tags: regex, grep, regex-negation

I need to search for a digit and € Symbol.

Examples:
**1€

2€**

But I also find \d€ in these examples:
1,2**0€**
1.3**0€**
1,9**9€**

So I need a string with only searches for *two characters* containing *a digit and a € symbol* without any digits before that.

I came up with, but it does not work
(?!\d)\d€

---

EDIT
It has to work with the InDesign GREP search and JavaScript

Comment: Does your `grep` support PCRE patterns (`-P` option)? What is the OS?

Comment: It has to work with the InDesign GREP search and JavaScript

Comment: I don't understand... whats wrong with just \d([.,]\d\d)?€

Comment: if you are searching entire line, try `^\d€$`... if your version supports word boundaries and you want to search anywhere in line, perhaps `\b\d€` would do..

Comment: @YossiVainshtein it now findes 1,20€ AND 1€ but it only should find 1€

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This, should do the job. Searches from the start of string for a decimal, followed by euro sign, in its unicode format.

```
 ^\d\u20AC
```